# $.getJSON not getting a response

Tags: jquery, ajax

So after a good couple of hours bashing my head against my keyboard trying to get IE to play nice with a $.ajax call, I've decided to try using $.getJSON instead.

```
 $.getJSON("addresshere", function(data) {
      alert(data); 
});
```

It doesn't seem to be getting to the alert and I'm not getting any errors in my console... not sure what I'm doing wrong.

*I've changed the address because it's a company website.

I'm using $.getJSON because I need to get data from another server. I've tried $.get and $.ajax but IE has a problem with both calls and it's blocking them.

EDIT: yes sorry this is a cross domain request. I'm using google Chrome to develop $.ajax and $.get worked fine in chrome I'm just having trouble with $.getJSON.

Comment: Is the server from the same origin ? If not, are CORS headers set ? You might have a problem with same origin policy.

Comment: Are you on localhost? Is `addresshere` in the same domain?

Comment: Is this a cross-domain request?

Comment: I need to have a CORS spiel ready to copy-paste for these questions...

Comment: @joeframbach You probably mean you need to have a bookmark to the identical question ready for closing.

Comment: Yeah but there's no reputation to gain from that :)

Comment: http://ternarylabs.github.com/porthole/ might be useful since you own both servers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed by the browser, because at this point there's no stopping you from proxying requests to bank websites, facebook, or whatever you feel like. It's a security concern. For more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

however, if you are only doing GET requests, and you are only using this for development (please do not do this in production), then you can use YQL to proxy the requests: http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax

Comment: Hi joeframbach all I'm trying to do is retrieve a page from a server and display it on another server. The server I'm trying to get the page from is ours and we give our clients some code to put on there site which displays the page from our site.